# How do i get my java code to restart automatically all over again instead of the program ending?

Tags: java

Currently im new to java, and im trying to get my code to restart from the top so essentially you can keep entering sentences until user cancels on purpose. Currently i keep getting an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
boolean run = true;
while(run) {
        for(;;) {


            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Hello Welcome To The Sentence Reverser !");
            System.out.println("Enter a sentence below to reverse.");
            String str = scan.nextLine();
            scan.close();
            String reversedStr = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
            System.out.println("Initial Sentence: " + str);
            System.out.println("Reversed Sentence: " + reversedStr);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: okay..sorry didnt know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once did something similar to this, this was for moderators to check specific user accounts. You basically re-call the search method after input handling. This way you can reset the program to a previous state.

```
/**
 * @author Stan van der Bend
 */
public class Scanner {

    private static final String CHARACTER_FILE_PATH = "data/characters";

    private static ArrayDeque<String> matches = new ArrayDeque<>(200);

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        search();
    }

    private static void search() throws IOException{

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter your desired keyword: ");

        String keyword = reader.readLine();

        System.out.println("Started scanning all files...");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(CHARACTER_FILE_PATH);

            Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    matches.addAll(Files
                            .readAllLines(path)
                            .stream()
                            .filter(line -> line.contains(keyword))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    );
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Make sure this is in the same directory as "+CHARACTER_FILE_PATH);
        }
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.out.println("Found "+matches.size()+" matches for the keyword "+keyword);

        matches.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(PlayerLogs::getDate)).forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("The scan toke " + duration + "ms to complete.");
        System.out.print("For another scan type -r ");

        matches.clear();

        if(reader.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("-r"))
            search();

        reader.close();
    }
}
```